# append row to cv::Mat by push_back std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a std::vector of the same data type as a cv::Mat. The number of elements in the vector is the same as the number of columns in the matrix. However, when I `cv::Mat::push_back` the vector it fails with:

```
... Pushed vector length is not equal to matrix row length in function 'push_back'
```

And here's a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int
main()
{
  cv::Mat m (2, 3, CV_32FC1);
  std::cout << "m has " << m.rows << " rows and " << m.cols << " cols\n"
            << m << "\n";

  std::vector<float> v {1,2,3};
  std::cout << "v has " << v.size() << " elements\n";

  m.push_back(v);

  return 0;
}
```

which returns:

```
m has 2 rows and 3 cols
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
v has 3 elements
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1078: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) Pushed vector length is not equal to matrix row length in function 'push_back'

Aborted
```

I know I can do something like:

```
m.push_back(cv::Mat (1, v.size(), CV_32FC1, v.data()));
```

but I was hoping to make it simpler.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The overload of `push_back` that takes a `vector` just does a `push_back(Mat(v));`. Now the problem with this is that the result of the constructor call has 1 column and `v.size()` rows. Hence, this particular overload works only for adding 1 or more rows into a single-column `Mat`.

Comment: As a side note, keep in mind that every call will likely mean a reallocation and copy of the whole buffer, so if you plan to append many rows, it may be worth considering a different approach.

Comment: @DanMašek thank you. I guess the answer is that it won't work. I'll use the extra verbose way. WRT the reallocation, on my actual program I know ahead if time the number of vectors to append so I reserve the space ahead of time. Thanks for the heads up though.